# How to find information about "bad value" error?

Tags: r, memory-management, out-of-memory, rstudio

I have some code which generates a report in a huge .csv file.

This involves 5k lines of code with various user-def functions that are applied to 80 databases - lets just say its complicated and doesn't need describing. Final product is a .csv with 3 columns and ~90M lines.

### Procedure:

1. import file-report .csv
2. make a loop for 80 databases, execute code for each
3. for each database - write intermediate result in current directory as .csv

**Before**, I used my local pc with 8Gb RAM, 8 cores, a good medium ranged machine.
It was difficult, 5 hours of execution, but it was OK, tested 999 times, no bugs.

**Now**, I'm on Windows Server 2016, a monster VM with 112Gb RAM, 64 cores etc.

### Question:

Why do I get the following message: `Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?)` or `Error: bad value` with no details after processing 10 databases out of 80?

There is no large vector to allocate yet, all my environment in total takes about 30Mb and computer uses only 1% of its capabilities.
In one iteration the code handles 1 database of at most 300Mb, plus 3-4 small dataframes of 4-5Mb.

What did I miss? Where to go to get info about this type of error?

Comment: Hi, can tell us at least what is the programming language and runtime you're using for this? It would be good if you provided a sample of your code...

I suspect that there's a memory limit involved and you're probably keeping multiple compies of your data. I would be glad to help, but you need to give us some more data.

Comment: It happens to me at 2 virtual machines (dev and prod) with R 3.6.2 installed using RStudio 1.2.5033.
The code is too huge to create a reproductible sample.
The essential to know - I am using following functions of import-export:
readxl - read_excel // data.table - fread // data.table - fwrite // writexl - write_xlsx

Comment: @MichałKapracki
And the code of 5k lines consists of veryfying the conformity of the data in these bases, if its correspond to a referring excel file, if columns are empty, etc. Nothing special really. Its just a big amount of simple check-ups of my data.

Comment: Well - I suppose that whole file would fit in memory, right? You probably have a couple transforms on the whole data that cause a lot of copies in the memory - this causes the data to actually take up more than is needed.

You could try to rework the code in such a way that you could work on the data in small parts.